# Should this question be migrated to signal processing?

Tags: discussion

This question was recently posted: [How to find poles of transfer function by looking at the step response?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38439/how-to-find-poles-of-transfer-function-by-looking-at-the-step-response)

My view is that it needs to be migrated to signal processing stack exchange because

- the community there will benefit more from the question
- contains little physics content
- Is being asked by someone probably doing a module in signal processing.

Are there other reasons why it should/should-not be asked here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, only your reason #2 is really a valid reason to migrate. That being said, nobody else seemed to have much of an opinion either way, so I went ahead and migrated it.

Comment: Fair enough, the other reasons justify it being migrated rather than closed I guess. The question has been upvoted twice, and one answer four times after migrating, so they seem to be OK with it.